# How to POST image to WordPress by React Native

Tags: wordpress, rest, react-native

My english not good, hope u can understand me.
I'm trying to POST a media file to WordPress by ReactNative.
But when i send request it allways respone that fail.
When i GET posts and another data that still ok.?
Can u help me to fix it?
Thanks all :D

That's my code:

```
upload = async ()=>{
    const base64 = require('base-64');
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('photo','filename');
    data.append('photo', {
        url: this.state.uriImage,
        type: this.state.type,
        name: this.state.fileName
    });
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + base64.encode("admin:admin"));
    await fetch('http://nhom2.dotplays.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: headers,
        body: data,
    }).then(res => {console.log(res)})
}
```

That' failed

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
blob:http://localhos…-c81bf1f94a97:59031 Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: Network request failed
TypeError: Network request failed

Answer (score -1):

try adding a catch to you fetch, it should give you more information on why the the post is failing, but i believe it's a server error when you hit the endpoint there with a POST.

```
//your previous code.....
await fetch('http://nhom2.dotplays.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    body: data,
}).then(res => {console.log(res)})
.catch((error) =>{
    // add this and see what you get in the console 
    console.error(error);
});
```